# React dispatch TypeError Object is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Помогите, не работает dispatch

```
import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import HotelList from './components/HotelList/HotelList'
import LoginForm from './components/auth/LoginForm/LoginForm'
import { useDispatch, useSelector, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { setHotels } from './reducers/hotel/actions'
import setToken from './reducers/auth/actions';

const App = (props) => {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(setToken('asda'));
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header isLoggedIn={auth.isLoggedIn}/>
         <Route path='/login' component={LoginForm}/>
         <Route exact path='/' component={() => <HotelList/>} />
        <button onClick={onClick}>{auth.token}</button>
       </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    token: '',
}

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action) {
        case 'SET_TOKEN':
            return { ...state, token: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default authReducer;
```

Actions:

```
const setToken = (token) => {
    return  {
        type: 'SET_TOKEN',
        payload: token,
    }
}

export default {
    setToken,
}
```

Ошибка :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ответить на Ваш вопрос нельзя потому что Вы не сделали или не показали ряд важных вещей.

1. Нет  Provider в App

   ```
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
   ```
2. Нет createStore

Возможна какая то проблема с компонентами - при необходимости в них должен быть connect.

Сделайте пример в
https://codesandbox.io/s
и поместите туда весь Ваш код - потому что смотреть надо целиком.
Пока исправьте пункты 1 и 2